# How to delete edges from a graph with some condition?

Tags: functions, function-construction, graphs-and-networks

I want to delete an edge and its reversed edge from a graph (if they exist in the graph).
It would be OK to use `EdgeDelete[g, {edge, Reverse[edge]}]` if these two are actually edges of the graph. However, in my case they may or may not be edges in the graph. So that code would cause error that I don't want if one or both of them are not edges of the graph. 
I tried the one below and it works but I'd would like ask if anyone know a better solution as I think this is too long and not so elegant.

```
g1 = Graph[{a \[UndirectedEdge] b, c \[UndirectedEdge] d, 
    e \[UndirectedEdge] f, g \[UndirectedEdge] h}];
g2 = If[EdgeQ[g1, #],
      EdgeDelete[g1, #], g1] &@a \[UndirectedEdge] b;
g2 = If[EdgeQ[g1, #],
     EdgeDelete[g1, #], g2] &@Reverse[a \[UndirectedEdge] b];
```

Comment: Is efficiency a concern? Graph modifications are expensive in Mathematica, especially repeated small modifications. Sometimes it makes sense to temporarily use a different representation of the graph, e.g. an adjacency matrix.

Comment: @Szabolcs efficiency is not a problem.

Comment: Your example shows an _undirected_ graph so the concept of "reversed edge" makes no sense. Also note that `Reverse` is not safe to use on edge specifications. What if the edge has a tag, e.g. `DirectedEdge["a", "b", 1]`?

Comment: Are all the real edges `UndirectedEdge`s? And do you want to delete all copies of them, or just multiples past the first one? (But also, yeah, what @Szabolcs said; I think it would help to hear a little more about your use case.)

Comment: All edges are undirected. I would be happy if all functions consider `a \[UndirectedEdge] b` to be same as `b \[UndirectedEdge] a` but they don't. `EdgeDelete` is an example. `EdgeDelete[g, a \[UndirectedEdge] b]`  would not delete `b \[UndirectedEdge] a]`.

Comment: If that is so, that would be a bug that you should report it to Wolfram. If you are looking to work around a bug, please ask about that explicitly, and demonstrate the bug. I am not aware of any such bugs, but I also won't be surprised if they exist.

Comment: Sorry probably I used functions which is not graph related. With that info I think I can simplify my code above. I'll delete it.

Comment: I see you edited your comment saying that `EdgeDelete` is sensitive to the ordering with which undirected edges are specified. Can you elaborate on this and give a small example that demonstrates it? Mention your Mathematica version. I am not able to reproduce this in 13.1.  If such a bug exists in some versions, I'd like to be aware, as it likely affects my graph package (IGraph/M).

Comment: @Szabolcs sorry probably I misremember that. I probably used some functions related to lists instead. I just tried `EdgeDelete` and it works.

Comment: Re @Trev's very good point: if you want to delete _all_ edges between `a` and `b` you can use `EdgeDelete[g, EdgeList[g, UndirectedEdge[a,b]]]`. Performance is probably not good ... Your approach with `EdgeQ` is also good and deletes just one of the edges between `a` and `b`.

Comment: If efficiency ever becomes an issue, I suspect you could speed things up a lot by sorting edges themselves, and then sorting the results of that. So, `Sort[Sort /@ pairs]`, but you can do that with one `Sort` if you'd rather. Then it's no more than linear time to step through that and weed out extras / reversals; maybe even one `DeleteDuplicates[pairs]` call, depending on exactly what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MMA is smart enough to sort the vertices. Therefore the "Reverse" is not needed.

```
g1 = Graph[{a \[UndirectedEdge] b, c \[UndirectedEdge] d, 
    e \[UndirectedEdge] f, g \[UndirectedEdge] h}, 
   VertexLabels -> Automatic];
g2 = EdgeDelete[g1, {a \[UndirectedEdge] b}]
```

[image]

To prevent an error with a not existing edge, you may use "EdgeQ:"

```
g2 = EdgeDelete[
  g1, {a \[UndirectedEdge] b, 
   If[EdgeQ[g1, q \[UndirectedEdge] w], q \[UndirectedEdge] w, Nothing]}]
```

[image]

But in this case the braces are needed, even if you have only one edge:

```
g2 = EdgeDelete[
  g1, {If[EdgeQ[g1, q \[UndirectedEdge] w], q \[UndirectedEdge] w, Nothing]}]
```

Otherwise an error message is generated.